# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was unhandled

Tags: hadoop, visual-studio-2013

While running process to Hadoop automated build from source in visual studio I am facing this error

> Exception: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll

Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you compiling vc++ file in Visual studio...? Me too faced same problem

Comment: Set output directory to solve the problem...